# Setup postfix as outgoing only MTA

Tags: linux, postfix

## Edit

I have wanted to clarify that I don't want my generated e-mails to be stored on this server. I want this server to only send, but not recieve e-mails and my sender address should appear as my registered domain name.

## Original Post

I want to setup my home server as email server for sending cron jobs and scheduled reports. I don't intend to recieve e-mails from this machine. I have a static ip and registered domain name. I have created an mx record for my domain name as mail.example.net and created a HOST(A) record for mail.example.net . I have checked and can see that I have no problem on the dns side. I have done this because most (or all?) mail servers wont accept my mails if I omit this step.

Here is my postfix main.cf file

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localdomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
mailbox_size_limit = 51200000
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = ipv4
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

`/etc/mailname` correctly points to `example.net` (not mail.example.net I think this is correct)

However, my mailq now looks like this

```
673CCB6EE9B      451 Wed Jul 19 11:29:07  server@example.net
(delivery temporarily suspended: connect to mail.example.net[my.ip.was.here]:25: Connection refused)
                                         root@example.net

6B155B6EF04      770 Wed Jul 19 12:45:13  root@example.net
(delivery temporarily suspended: connect to mail.example.net[my.ip.was.here]:25: Connection refused)
                                         root@example.net

52EA3B6EF01      771 Wed Jul 19 12:15:57  root@example.net
(delivery temporarily suspended: connect to mail.example.net[my.ip.was.here]:25: Connection refused)
                                         root@example.net
```

As you can see, postfix is trying to access port 25 on my public ip address to send e-mails for some reason, but port 25 is not enabled in my modem because I don't want to recieve e-mails. I am thinking I have some kind of configuration error.

Comment: If you want emails addressed to your domain to actually be delivered somewhere, you need to set the MX record to a server that is receiving them. If you want automatically generated emails to stay on the server instead, you need to configure your server to deliver them locally instead. It is all described in the Postfix documentation, which you should re-read.

Comment: @JennyD I want automatically generated emails to be delivered somewhere else, and I want my domain name displayed as sender e-mail address like root@example.com, I have created mx record because other smtp servers checks to verify if e-mail address is legit

Comment: When you do a fresh install Postfix on Debian, it asks you what kind of base configuration you want. (I'm pretty sure you can also get to that point by `dpkg-reconfigure postfix`.) One of the options is for a system that is "not connected to the Internet" and delivers mail strictly locally, not through a smarthost; I think they call that one `Local only`. I don't know off hand what exact settings this translates to, but switching to that might be a better starting point than trying to tweak the configuration you have, particularly seeing as there appears to be nothing special about it.

Comment: If you want the emails to be delivered elsewhere, then again, go read the documentation and configure postfix to rewrite it to the correct destination.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your exact question, but probably a solution to your real problem.

What you want is to set it up as a so-called Null Client. Basically, send-only. In Postfix you have chosen a fully fledged MTA which can do way more than that. I've been in a similar situation and decided that it doesn't make sense to use Postfix just for this small subset of tasks. A bit like buying a car with no intention to drive, but just for shelter, when a cheap and smaller shed will do.

Setup complexity aside, there's also resources to think about. And security. So te me, it made sense to find a smaller package that isn't a fully fledged MTA but does just send my alerts, mainly Fail2Ban and Monit.

I picked MSMTP: http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/doc/msmtp.html

And use it for this purpose now for years on production machines. I have it setup to only ever send to myself. As the sender e-mail is not set up to be a true mailbox, it fails many anti-spam measures so you have to whitelist it where you want to receive it.

If you want to persist with Postfix, you need to follow the null client config setup documentation:

http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client

Comment: Null client looks promising, I am looking into it

Answer (score 0):

Postfix is connecting to your public IP (`mail.example.net[xx.xx.xx.xx]:25: Connection refused)`) because

1. it tries to send mail TO (not just from) `root@example.net`
2. the `example.net` is not in its `mydestination` (that actually seems to be correct) and
3. the `MX` record for your `example.net` points to that IP.

You need to either

- change the destination address to be something else than an address within this domain or
- fix the `MX` to point to whichever server is supposed to handle the mail for `example.net`.

You state that...

> I have created an mx record for my domain name as mail.example.net and
>   created a HOST(`A`) record for `mail.example.net`. I have checked and can
>   see that I have no problem on the dns side. I have done this because
>   most (or all?) mail servers wont accept my mails if I omit this step.

This may actually be your problem. The checks are for `HELO` vs. `A` vs. `PTR`; it's false to think that an originating server must be among `MX` records: sending and receiving mail isn't the same thing!

You may want to study [*Sender Policy Framework* (SPF)](http://www.openspf.org/Introduction). It's possible to tell the receiver that this server is a permitted sender for `example.net`, e.g.

```
example.net.  TXT  "v=spf1 ip4:198.51.100.5 include:aspmx.googlemail.com -all"
```

In this example sending is permitted for Gmail and IP address `198.51.100.5` & denied for rest.

Comment: Do you know why it is trying to send a mail to root@example.com?

Comment: By default, Cron sends mail to the user. You can change that with `MAILTO=your.actual@example.com` at the beginning of the `crontab` for user crontabs, but in global cronjobs this isn't possible. Maybe you could use aliases. (Or even transport maps... there are many ways to achieve things with Postfix.)